# How to $project specific fields after $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a query like

```
let issuerPaid = await ChallengeModel.aggregate([
    { $match: {voucher_paid_by: 'issuer', challenge_by_appuser: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)} },
    { $lookup: {from: 'vouchers',localField: 'voucher_id',foreignField: '_id',as: 'voucher'} },
    { $lookup: {from: 'appusers',localField: 'challenge_loser',foreignField: '_id',as: 'challenge_loser'} },
]);
```

And it results like

```
{
    "issuerPaid": [
        {
            "_id": "5b86b18afa04445392ff6542",
            "voucher_id": "5b7cfa381496bea7d6c5bea4",
            "voucher_paid_by": "loser",
            "challenge_loser": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b75643c0a97791bcc9ed64c",
                    "status": "1",
                    "last_name": "Gmail",
                    "first_name": "Vishwas",
                    "created_at": "2018-08-16T11:47:08.475Z",
                    "updated_at": "2018-08-28T12:54:45.462Z"
                }
            ],
            "voucher": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b7cfa381496bea7d6c5bea4",
                    "voucher_name": "Walora",
                    "voucher_description": "Where fashion meets fitness! Get a 20% discount on all active wear purchases",
                    "voucher_disclaimer": "",
                    "voucher_validity": "2018-10-31 00:00:00.666",
                    "voucher_logo": "/vouchers/5b7cf73ccee4b5b7cf73ccee85.jpg",
                    "status": "1",
                    "created_at": "2018-08-22T05:52:56.156Z",
                    "updated_at": "2018-08-22T05:52:56.156Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But it returns all fields of `appusers`. But i only want `appusers`'s `first_name` and `last_name`.

I tried to `$unwind` it and `$project` only `first_name` and `last_name` but when there is no `voucher_id` then it returns 0 record, while i want it to return record if it's not there. So i was unable to use `$unwind`.

I want result to look like

```
{
    "issuerPaid": [
        {
            "_id": "5b86b18afa04445392ff6542",
            "voucher_id": "5b7cfa381496bea7d6c5bea4",
            "voucher_paid_by": "loser",
            "challenge_loser": [
                {
                    "last_name": "Gmail",
                    "first_name": "Vishwas"
                }
            ],
            "voucher": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b7cfa381496bea7d6c5bea4",
                    "voucher_name": "Walora"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And now i'm having trouble in projecting specific fields.

Please help.

Comment: You can use lookup pipeline in 3.6 and use project stage inside lookup pipeline to project specific fields like `{"$lookup":{   "from":"appusers",   "let":{"challenge_loser":"$challenge_loser"},   "pipeline":[     {"$match":{       "$expr":{"$eq":["$$challenge_loser","$_id"]}     }},     {"$project":{"last_name":1,"first_name":1}}   ],   "as":"challenge_loser" }}`